# Batch, if line does not have text, echo previous line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to read a text file line by line and if a line is null which I expect it shouldn't be then echo -1 line.

The text file contains text like this:

```
Town
Hereford
C:\Installer.exe
192840573



Town
Greenock
C:\Installer.exe
192840573



Town
York



Town
Ipswich
C:\Installer.exe
192840573
```

What I would like to do is echo that York does not have the Installer.exe
This varies from town to town and multiple towns may have the installer missing.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I entered the question the file has new lines I have indicated with \r\n but the post reformatted.

Comment: Search the net and try lots of examples that I'm not sure on their process.

Comment: I also need to identify is the town has the installer check if the size is as expected e.g 192840573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SET "Town="
SET "Townname="
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25568537.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED town IF NOT DEFINED townname SET "townname=%%a"
 IF /i "%%a"=="Town" (
  IF DEFINED townname CALL ECHO %%townname%%
  SET "Town=Y"
  SET "Townname="
 )
 IF /i "%%a"=="C:\Installer.exe" SET "Townname="&SET "town="
)

IF DEFINED town IF DEFINED townname CALL ECHO %%townname%%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25568537.txt` containing your data for my testing.

note that batch environment variables are case-insensitive. The `if /i` syntax makes the string-comparisons case-insensitive; probably not necessary here, but also harmless in this instance.

Comment: @corythompson - This solution can be made nearly 5 times faster if delayed expansion is enabled and `CALL ECHO %%townname%%` is replaced by `echo !townname!`

Answer (score 0):

Magoo's solution works, but it can be quite slow with a large file.

Here is another solution that uses FINDSTR to search across line breaks. If the file is small, then it doesn't matter. But if the file has many thousands of lines, then this solution is significantly faster (factor of 6 on my machine). This solution is still marginally faster than Magoo's solution even if it is modified to use delayed expansion.

I have to create a temp copy with extra lines appended just in case the last Town is missing the installer.

My code assumes the file is named test.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set file=test.txt

::Define LF variable containing a linefeed (0x0A)
set ^"LF=^

^" Above empty line is critical - DO NOT REMOVE

::Define CR variable containing a carriage return (0x0D)
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

(type "%file%"&echo(&echo()>"%file%.new"
findstr /ir /c:"[a-z].*!CR!*!lf!!CR!*!LF!" "%file%.new"
del "%file%.new"
```